# How do I make an if statement that repeats itself if the requirements are still not met?

Tags: c++

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i = 0;

    int players;
    int silenceAmount;
    int bleedAmount;
    int bleedDays;
    int playersAlive;
    int playersDead;
    int playersAllowed = 6;

    cout << "How many players are playing (can only be " << playersAllowed << ")? ";
    cin >> players;
    if (players > playersAllowed) (
            cout << "There an only be " << playersAllowed << " players. Please select another number. ");
            cin >> players;

    cout << "There are " << players << " players.\n\n";



    return 0;

}
```

this works for only one time and I want it to work until it gets a number less than or equal to 6.

Comment: Use a loop.  There are plenty to chose from: `while`, `do..while`, and `for` are all valid choices.

Comment: Loops are probably in the second lesson. :)

Comment: A repeating `if` statement, is called a `while` loop.

Comment: ..and presumably greater than zero?

Answer (score 3):

Repeating `if` statements are generally done as a `while` loop. In your code, when you have

```
if (players > playersAllowed)
```

You should simply change it do

```
while (players > playersAllowed)
```

Also, while I'm at it, the syntax you have for your `if` statement is not correct for what you are trying to do. You should replace `(` and `)` by `{` and `}` respectively. Also, the ending bracket is in the incorrect place.

In the end, your loop would be something like this:

```
while (players > playersAllowed) {
    cout << "There can only be " << playersAllowed << " players. Please select another number: ";
    cin >> players;
}
```

Note that this doesn't take into account someone entering `jfksdjfs` for a number.

Comment: Genius. Thank you so much for your help, I will try this out right now.